# Product position in Google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, ecommerce

The [instructions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters) for product position `pr<productIndex>ps` is the following.  What is the use case of the product position parameter in the google measurement protocol? Where does this show up in google analytics as I haven't been able to see it within google analytics.

> **Product Position**
>
> Optional.
>
> The product's position in a list or collection. Product index must be
>   a positive integer between 1 and 200, inclusive. For analytics.js the
>   Enhanced Ecommerce plugin must be installed before using this field.

Comment: Sorry mate, this is too broad question. You are asking us to provide you a examples, yet you don't understand when this would be used.

Comment: Well, let's rephrase the question then. What is the use case of the product position parameter in the google measurement protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The product list position is used, at least, in the Product List Performance reports. When sending in product impressions, you can include the product position, as well as the product list name. The `Product List Position` can be included as a primary dimension like so:

[image]

[image]

Clicking into each position shows you the products that occupied that position within the respective product list.

Comment: Perfect explanation!